# Powershell. Domain controller Status

Tags: powershell

When using Active Directory Users and Computers, it is possible to right click on the domain and select "Change Domain Controller".

This gives a list of all DC's and their Status (online/Unavailable)

How can I get that status using powershell?

Have tried:

Get-ADDomainController -identity SERVERNAME

It gives me a lot of information about that DC, but not the status.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) checking the availability via `Test-Connection` to the output of `Get-ADDomainController`:

```
Get-ADDomainController |
   select *, @{n='Online';e={[bool](Test-Connection $_.IPv4Address 2>$null)}}
```

Comment: Isn't this "just" a ping test? I think the ADUC Status is more thorough.

Comment: @Lisbjerg: Yes, `Test-Connection` is a ping test. I don't know if `dsa.msc` does anything different from that.